# social.actions.do_complete not working in python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, python-social-auth

I am trying to add email authentication with python-social-auth.

[Documentation](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/email.html) says that:

`Form submit should go to /complete/email, or if it goes to your view, then your view should complete the process calling social.actions.do_complete`

In my case, the form goes to my own view and at the end I should call `do_complete`. I searched a lot but was not able to find any documentation on this method. I looked at the source code and the definition is:

```
def do_complete(backend, login, user=None, redirect_name='next',
            *args, **kwargs)
```

But how do I give this method all those parameters, i.e. backend, login(what is login?) and etc from my django view?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is load your backend manually like this:

```
from social.apps.django_app.utils import load_strategy, load_backend
strategy = load_strategy(self.request)
backend = load_backend(strategy, 'username', "social:complete")
```

where `username` is the name of backend and then call `do_complete` like this:

```
do_complete(backend, login, user)
```

where `backend` is your previously obtained backend, `login` is a login function (look at `_do_login` function from `social.apps.django_app.views`) and `user` is your user instance, which you have create/authenticated etc in your view.
Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: In the version I just used (3.1.0), load_strategy and load_backend were found in social_django.utils